# Return another object in an object's method

Tags: ruby, oop

Is there a way to do this in ruby?

```
a = UnauthenticatedClient.new
a.class #=> #<UnauthenticatedClient>

a.login!("username", "password")
a.class #=> #<AuthenticatedClient>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
a = UnauthenticatedClient.new
a.class #=> #<Unauthenticated>

a = a.login!("username", "password")
a.class #=> #<Authenticated>
```

A method may return a different object, but it cannot change the reference to that object:

```
class UnauthenticatedClient
  def login!(username, password)
    # do the login process...
    Authenticated.new(authentication_params) # returns a new object of type Authenticated
  end
end
```

You can also consider using attributes instead of classes to determine whether the client is authenticated or not:

```
a = Client.new
a.class #=> #<Client>
a.authenticated? # false

a.login!("username", "password")
a.class #=> #<Client>
a.authenticated? # true
```

Comment: The reason is: variables aren't objects. If you wanted to change a variable, you would have to either call a method on it (which you can't, because it's not an object and you cannot call methods on something which isn't an object), or you would have to pass it as an argument to a method (which you can't, because it's not an object and you cannot pass something which isn't an object as an argument). You can only dereference or assign variables. (Note, there are some reflective methods that take the *name* of a variable as an argument and then assign to it. But not for globals.)